# Are there impulse turbines operating on hot exhaust gas?

Tags: turbines

Are there impulse turbines that operate efficiently on hot exhaust gases rather than water as the working fluid?

Im thinking about something analogous to a water wheel, since it seems that bucket/blade design in such a turbine would be much easier to do for an amateur since it wouldn't depend so closely on the intended operating conditions as for turbines that rotate in a perpendicular plane to the flow

Comment: Do you mean they would be different from turbochargers ?

Comment: Gases are compressible. Liquids are not (to a good approximation). A "water wheel" turbine design that works well for liquids won't work so well for a gas. But conventional-looking axial flow turbines can use a combination of impulse and reaction to drive them. Steam turbines have been designed that way.

Comment: In fact *efficient* impulse turbines *do* depend closely on the intended operating conditions. For Pelton wheel type turbines, for example, the fluid inlet velocity has to be close to twice the velocity of the buckets on the wheel.